# Extract second last IP address from a list of IP using RegEx

Tags: regex

I want to extract the second last IP address from the below expression using regex:

```
18.223.194.15, 56.99.45.32, 32.65.27.65, 52.89.22.5, 123.12.22.53
```

Should get 52.89.22.5 from the above

```
16.45.98.14, 10.22.102.16
```

Should get 16.45.98.14 from the above

I was able to get the last IP or the first IP using the below regex commands but I am having trouble getting the second last ip

To get the last IP

```
(?<IP>([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})+$
```

To get the first IP

```
(?<IP>([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}),.*
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `\b\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}(?=, \d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}$)`.

Comment: Is the format consistent? How about [`^(?:.*, )?(?<IP>(?:\d{1,3}\.?\b){4}),`](https://regex101.com/r/mQbJi7/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the second last one, and match the last one asserting the end of the string after it.

```
\b(?<IP>(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}), (?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LbK0YQ/1).

Answer (score 0):

You need a regex flavour with some form of lookahead/lookbehind.

This could take the form of a capture group surrounded by something.

Assume regex has basic form: `^A(xA)*$` or `^(Ax)*A$`

`A` is something of interest. `x` is a separator.

- for final `A`: `^(Ax)*(A)$`
- for 2nd-to-last `A`: `^(Ax)*(A)xA$`
- for (n+1)th-to-last `A`: `^(Ax)*(A)(xA){n}$`

In all cases, result is in second capture group.