# How to get everything before the second-to-last occurrence with a regex?

Tags: regex

I need everything that's behind the second-to-last comma and space of my string.

Example:

input:
`Jan 23, 2023, October 23, 2022, 2 October 23, 2022, Jan 23, 2023`

output: `Jan 23, 2023, October 23, 2022, 2 October 23, 2022`

I tried this but this gives me the contrary result and it doesn't handle the space.

`([^,]+),[^,]+$`

https://regex101.com/r/IPFj0y/1

Comment: Maybe `^.*(?=\/[^\/\n]+\/[^\/\n]+\/?$)`?

Comment: This has same form of solution as https://stackoverflow.com/a/73739411/10971581 with `x` being comma+space and `A` being a regex that matches a single field. Just edit to merge first and second capture groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick in the first capturing group:

```
(.*)(?=(, .*, ))
```

Explanation: first capture group captures everything up until the positive lookahead  group (?=). Inside the positive lookahead I added the second to last rule you seeked, which is comma and space followed by anything and then another comma and space.

Answer (score 0):

You can match using this regex:

```bash
(.*\b\d{4}),.*
```

and replace with `'$1`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VEVhHL/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(.*\b\d{4})`: Match any text until last 4 digits. Due to greedy nature of `.*` quantifier it will match longest possible string before matching last 4 digits
- `,`: Match a comma
- `.*`: Match everything till end